# Kernel Panic after Installation Issues with Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, kernel, supermicro, kernel-panic

**Update 2**

The installation from Update 1 was successful.

**Update 1**

Just removed RAID10 from all six drives, and RAID10 configured only the first four devices.  After doing so, the installation was able to proceed past the Ubuntu splash screen.  So this looks to be a problem with one of the hard drives, or drive interfaces.  I will be back to confirm this.

**Issue**

Receiving this error message after reboot as result of the troubleshooting steps taken in this post, HT Link Sync Error after Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Installation:

> [9.834923] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1).

I believe this to be a separate issue as the installation process will not proceed beyond this point.  Before troubleshooting, the system could make it to the point of partitioning before encountering the problems described in the aforementioned post.

**Hardware**

CPU: AMD OPTERON X12 6172 G34 2.1G 18MB

Motherboard: Supermicro H8QG6-F

HDD: WD Caviar Green 2TB 5.4K RPM

**Troubleshooting**

I removed the RAID10 configuration, and formatted a single drive using the onboard LSI disk management tool of this motherboard: Supermicro H8QG6-F.  This did not resolve the issue - received the same kernel panic error.

I can boot into rescue mode off the Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS installation disk successfully, but I am uncertain where to go from here as many of the tools recommended in troubleshooting documentation is unavailable in the rescue mode console.

There is a possible solution I discovered on another site regarding a rebuild of initrd, [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuild-the-initial-ramdisk-image/) that linked from this [post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kernel-panic-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-and-solution/).  I have not had the opportunity to test this yet.

My biggest question is: how can the drives or necessary boot tables become so ruined that it will not boot the files necessary to perform an installation and instead throw the error above?

The next question is: What steps/approaches can be taken to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be driver/firmware for you controller is not in initramfs for 10.04. If that is the case - only way for you to get LTS release is to use backported kernel.

Try installing ubuntu 10.04.3 via `debootstrap` from newer images (e.g., Oneiric) or hack original DVD and place newer kernel/initramfs there.

Also as workaround you can install system on disks plugged in onboard SATA controller.

Comment: So I was able to RAID10 four of the six drives, and install Ubuntu on it without a problem.  This leads me to believe that there is a problem with one of the two drives not RAID-ed.  Could there be anything else wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have all drives plugged into an `LSI 2008` or some of them plugged in `AMD SP5100`?

Comment: Sorry, I just came across this and realized I did not give you the proper Kudos...I never rolled back to the previous versions of Ubuntu.  It didn't resolve the issue, but since yours was the only answer on here, and I did give it a whirl I figured I'd give you the answer.